# Handle different markets (language / locale) in Angular 2 application using an Web Api

Tags: api, pipe, angular

I could use some advice how I should handle different markets in my angular 2 application. By that I mean a new market (like the German market) where the language is in German, as an example. Right now, I have hardcoded the text inside the html (in english ofc) to make it easy for myself.

An example you see here:

```
<div class="row">
   <h2>Booking number: {{bookingNumber}}</h2>                           
   Your changes has been confirmed.                                                
</div>
```

I have read something about pipes in angular 2, and i guess I should be using something like that. My problem is, that I really don't know where to start. 
Already have an Web Api application created in Visual Studio 2015 which I can use and call.

I'm thinking of making two lists in my Web Api project (one for english, one for german), but there should still be some sort of indicator. By that I mean something like:

```
BOOKING_NUMBER_TEXT, 'the text in english or german'
CONFIRMATION_TEXT, 'the text...'
```

That list should have two params like, string string or something like that.. any idea how I could make this?

From my angular 2 application, I'm thinking of calling the api and given it an id (number, lets say 1 and 2, where 1 = english, 2 = germany)
My Web Api finds the correct list and sends it back as JSON.

Then I'm guessing of building a pipe my own where I can filter the words I set in the html. I'm thinking of something like:

```
<div class="row">
   <h2>{{BOOKING_NUMBER_TEXT | 'PIPE NAME' }}: {{bookingNumber}}</h2>                           
   {{CONFIRMATION_TEXT | 'PIPE NAME' }}.                                                
</div>
```

So when it has name BOOKING_NUMBER_TEXT, it should look into the pipe which has the list object, and take out the text from the right one and place it instead.

Is that a good plan or can you maybe give any advice? (I'm don't want to use any translate angular 2 frameworks, because I have to do different things on each market)

Cheers :)

**UPDATE**

Ok.. I have created some test data and allowed it to be send via my Web Api. Here is how it looks.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> createEnglishLocaleKeys()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Locale_EN = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Account Component
        Locale_EN.Add("ACCOUNT_LOGIN_TEXT", "Login");
        Locale_EN.Add("ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_TEXT", "Logout");

        // Booking Component
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_ACTIVE_HEADER_TEXT", "ACTIVE BOOKINGS");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LOADING_TEXT", "Loading bookings");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_NONACTIVE_HEADER_TEXT", "NON ACTIVE BOOKINGS");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_NOPREBOOKING_TEXT", "You currently do not have any previous bookings");

        // Booking List Component
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_BOOKINGNUMBER_TEXT", "Booking number");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_LEAVING_TEXT", "Leaving");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_RETURNING_TEXT", "Returning");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_ROUTE_TEXT", "Route");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_PASSENGERS_TEXT", "Passengers");
        Locale_EN.Add("BOOKING_LIST_VEHICLETYPE_TEXT", "Vehicle type");

        // Menu Component

        // Passenger Component

        // DepartureDate Component

        // Confirmation Component

        Locale_EN.Add("KEY_NOT_FOUND", "KEY NOT FOUND");

        return Locale_EN;
    }
```

Have created an LocaleController which takes a string locale "EN" or "DE" as parameter. Then I'm injecting a service for the controller, which will, based on the locale string choose which method to run (For now I'm only sending back the LocaleEN dictionary).

***How can I create an value in my Angular 2 application which should be EN as default and should be changeable?***

By changeable, you should be able to set it in the URL or some sort of, like:

```
localhost:3000/amendment?locale=DE
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here:

- You could HTTP content negotiation Conneg - See this link: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/10/understanding-http-content-negotiation/) and the `Accept-Language` to tell the server which messages to return.
- You need to wait for messages to be there before displaying the screen with for example: `<div ngIf="messages">…</div>`
- I don't think you need to implement a pipe to display messages if they are defined in a map (key / value): `{{messages['SOME_KEY']}}`
- If messages correspond to list a custom filtering pipe can be implemented and used like that: `{{messages | key:'SOME_KEY'}}`

The implementation of this pipe could be:

```
@Pipe({name: 'key'})
export class KeyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    // Assuming the message structure is:
    // { key: 'SOME_KEY', value: 'some message' }
    return value.find((message) => {
      return (message.key === args[0]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. I take a look after I have made some test data in my Web Api :)

Comment: Have made an update to my post.. please take a look if you have spare time.